# How to pass an object to a custom tag [in Spring MVC]?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, custom-tag

In Spring MVC, my code returns a ModelAndView with the model being object of class Foo.
Class Foo has a method

```
public Zoo getZoo()
```

In the JSP view i would like to pass the model object's Zoo to a custom tag.
I have a custom tag named doForObject, (which should do some reflection on the passed object). The corresponding tag Class has

```
public void setObject(Object object) {
    this.object = object;
}
```

How do I pass Foo's Zoo to this custom tag?
I tried both this:

```
<my:doForObject object="${model.zoo" />
```

as well as

```
<my:doForObject>
    <jsp:attribute name="object">${model.zoo}</jsp:attribute>
</my:doForObject>
```

and even this didn't work

```
<c:set var="obj" value="${model.zoo}" />
<my:doForObject object="${obj}" />
```

but in all 3 cases i get errors when the JSP is invoked.
For example, for the last attempt i got the error message

```
According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute object does not accept any expressions
```

The model object (instance of Foo) was created (for simplicity) as follows:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
foo.setZoo(zoo);
```

Comment: How about adding the error and the code that initializes your model.

Comment: may object is reserved key